Using HTTPClient to send JSON content as a string with application/json content type
I'm using an HTTPClient in a C# project and I'm trying to send JSON content with a JSON content type.  The POST messages always send as form data.
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();


WorkRequest workRequest = new WorkRequest()
{
   f1 = "asdf",
   ....
};

var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(workRequest));
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

// Send the ACK request to the workflow for final processing
await client.PostAsync(oxxoWorkflowAckUri, content);


I've tried countless samples I found online, and it's always sent as content type form data.
Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you

Your code is mostly correct but the StringContent constructor doesn't automatically set the content type to JSON, so if you manually set the header after creating the StringContent, it can sometimes fail to apply.
Set the Content-Type directly in the Constructor:
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text.Json;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

WorkRequest workRequest = new WorkRequest
{
   f1 = "asdf",
};

string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(workRequest);

var content = new StringContent(jsonString, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

await client.PostAsync(oxxoWorkflowAckUri, content);

Edited.

Thank you for your response.  Unfortunately, I had already tried that and countless other things.  The code above works perfectly if I'm using .Net 4.8.  If I use .Net 8.0, the content that goes over the wire is always "$content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".  Any other ideas?  THX

.NET 8.0 has slightly different behaviors regarding the default handling of HTTP content types in HttpClient. Edited my answer above with some changes in the code.

Thank you again for responding.  I copied your code verbatim and used the System.Text.Json.Serialize it's still failing with the same issue.  Do I need to delete any of the HTTPClient headers or anything else?

Yeah that would be a good idea, try using content.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Clear(); then set the contentType with:  content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "application/json";
